# "data on my iPad" or "data in my iPad"

Tags: american-english, nuance

Which is correct and are there any differences in meaning or nuance?

```
I have the data on my iPad

I have the data in my iPad
```

I searched `data on my iPad` and `data in my iPad` on google, and got many results on both sentences.

Comment: [*The files are **in** the computer*?!?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TV3Oncvz_cU) (And yet, nevertheless, the data is *on* your iPad, for some reason.)

Comment: So is it more common to say `the data is on my iPad`?

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch Yes, thank you! That is the exact answer I was looking for! If you could post the link, I will accept yours as the answer.

Comment: This one is up in the air.  One tends to think of data *on* a pad (even if an iPad), while data is `in` a computer.  I would guess that a consensus on this point has not yet coalesced yet.

Comment: @DanBron, I disagree. I say and hear "the files are **on** the computer" more often.

Comment: @Mike, did you click the link?

Comment: @DanBron, didn't realize you were joking.